# What is the Android PhoneStateListener's Behavior When Called Multiple Times?

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, phone-state-listener

My service has a PhoneStateListener that overrides the onCellInfoChanged method. When running on Android Studio, it'll log whenever the method is called. Based on the logs, it seems that sometimes the method gets called consecutively (a couple milliseconds between logs).

```java
public class OnCellChangeService extends Service
{
    // other field declarations

    private PhoneStateListener mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener()
    {
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        public void onCellInfoChanged(List<CellInfo> cellInfoList)
        {
            String timeStamp = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
            List<CellNetwork> cellNetworks = setCellNetwork(cellInfoList);
            String networkStrength = "";
            int index = 1;
            for (CellNetwork cell : cellNetworks)
                networkStrength += String.format("%s (%d)%s\n", timeStamp, index++, cell.record());

            try {
                writer.write(networkStrength);
                writer.flush();
                Log.d("Phone Listener", "Cell Change");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

   // rest of service

}
```

All the listener does is take the cellInfoList, calls another method to get a list that contains a list of custom class objects made from a subset of the original list. It writes to a file with a time stamp and other various pieces of information from each list object.

When the listener's method is called again while the same method is executing, does the current method stop and restart for the new call? Does it run in a separate thread of execution? Does it wait for the method to finish executing? If another call does halt or interfere with the same method executing, how could I implement threading and/or synchronization to make sure every called is executed in full while maintaining order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callbacks from `PhoneStateListener` are all made on the main (UI) thread. Therefore, each callback method will run to completion before the next one is called.

Comment: When the callback method is running, does that effectively disable callbacks until it is complete then? This makes me wonder about potentially missing callbacks if the method takes too long. If so, I assume running a thread when the callback method is called (to process outside the UI thread) would be a way to help ensure no callback is block/missed?

Comment: You won't miss any callbacks. They are queued, so as soon as the method returns if there is another one waiting in the queue you will get that one. Of course you shouldn't do a substantial amount of processing in the callback because it is called on the main (UI) thread and can make your application unresponsive. If you need to do a lot of processing you should start a background thread and do your processing there.